# Bing Maps infobox with htmlcontent doesn't show close button

Tags: javascript, html, bing-maps

This is a part of the JavaScript code I use:

```
infobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
infobox.setHtmlContent(myHtmlContent);
infobox.setOptions({
  showPointer: false,
  showCloseButton: true,
  offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 25),
  visible: true
});
```

Is it possible that the 'showCloseButton' option doesn't work when using setHtmlContent? Or am I missing something?

**update:**
By adding this code manually I'm able to close the infobox, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to close the infobox:

```
'<a class="infobox-close" href="javascript:closeInfobox()">x</a>'
```

and the Javascript function:

```
function closeInfobox() {
  infobox.setOptions({ visible: false });
}
```

Comment: That looks nice, also, with regard to your comment '... _not sure if this is the correct way to close the infobox_', I found a [sample](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/deleteinfobox) which indicates that closing the infobox is accomplished by `infobox.setMap(null);`

Answer (score 2):

The show close button is only for when you are using the default infobox template. When you use custom HTML that functionality is overridden. Your approach of using a link that calls JavaScript to close the infobox is the correct approach to take.

Comment: Good, too bad this information is missing from the documentation!

Comment: Actually the documentation does mention this "showCloseButton: This property is ignored if custom HTML is used to represent the info box.": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675210.aspx

Comment: That is the Bing Maps Interactive SDK. It's not documentation, but a bunch of examples on implementation. In the custom HTML content example the showCloseButton property is set to true to show you that it doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks @rbrundritt. 
My first experience with Bing Maps + DbGeometry is that documentation could be better with more examples or just a few extra sentences compared to Google.
e.g. the DbGeometry.FromText method ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506050(v=vs.110).aspx )
What are the possible SRID's, what exactly is wellKnownText etc..

Comment: There are a lot of different possible SRID values. You most likely want to use SRID 4326. DbGeometry is actually a subset of the spatial functionality in SQL's Microsoft.SQL.Types library. The SRID's are standards that are managed by the EPSG: http://www.epsg.org/